# extract a queryparam with $ symbol in apigee

Tags: rest, uri, apigee

How to extract a Query Param with $ symbol in apigee using extract variable eg $filter The URL and query param is like this http://example.api.net/extract_dollar?$filter=abc&$format=json

Here i have to extract the Query Param variable $filter

Answer (score 0):

The $ character isn't URI compliant and will be escaped (or not work at all) so it should come in as %24filter rather than $filter.

That said, I was able to use the AssignMessage Policy to set a variable accessing the queryparam $hello (sent in either as a $ or a %24 from my console).

```
<AssignVariable>
    <Name>name</Name>
    <Value/>
  <Ref>request.queryparam.$hello</Ref>
</AssignVariable>
```

Really, it shouldn't work so keep in mind that when you use non-standard naming practices like dollar signs in your query params it may stop working sometime in the future, but this will get you there for now.